# Dynamic localisation in kendo ui for angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In the example below the locale information loaded statically

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { load } from '@telerik/kendo-intl';
load(
  require(`json!cldr-data/main/bg/numbers.json`),
  require(`json!cldr-data/main/bg/currencies.json`),
  require(`json!cldr-data/main/bg/ca-gregorian.json`),
  require(`json!cldr-data/main/bg/timeZoneNames.json`)
);

@NgModule({
    bootstrap:    [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports:      [BrowserModule],
    providers:    [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'bg-BG' }]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I know how to load the cldr data dynamically. But the `CldrIntlService` requires a "static" `locale` to be injected. As the user can change the `locale` in my app at any time I would like the `CldrIntlService` service to be updated with the new `locale` after the new CLDR data has been fetched. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

The `CldrIntlService` does not require static locale, but Angular requires it. You can read more about it here:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

As for the problem - at the current stage Angular suggests to use the router to handle the different localization scenarios. So in your case you can inject different instances of the service using the router and navigate to that page.